# Downgrade GLIBC version on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: glibc

Is there any way by which I can downgrade GLIBC version from 2.31 to 2.29 on my Ubuntu 20.04.4?

I am trying to run kedro application on docker which gives me following error:

OSError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/kedro/libshorttext/libshorttext/classifier/learner/liblinear/python/../liblinear.so.1)

Comment: `libm.so` should be updated at the sametime as `libc.so`. I would be looking at why that is the case and begin by looking at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6`

Comment: The object `GLIBC_2.29` ***is*** present in the 20.04 libc6→libm.so.6 : `objdump -x /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2.29`  .... and `objdump -x /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 | grep GLIBC`

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way by which I can downgrade GLIBC version from 2.31 to 2.29 on my Ubuntu 20.04.4?

1. If you succeed, your system will (very likely) become un-bootable
2. Your problem is *elsewhere*: a version of `libm.so.6` that you have (version 2.31 presumably) *should* already define `GLIBC_2.29` (newer versions of GLIBC support programs linked against older versions).

You should first verify that you do in fact have an undamaged installation of `libc6` version 2.31 (possibly re-install this package).

Once you have, you can confirm that your `libm.so.6` has `GLIBC_2.29` version label like so:

```
readelf -V /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2.29
...
  450:   9h(GLIBC_2.26)    a (GLIBC_2.27)    8 (GLIBC_2.25)    c (GLIBC_2.29)
  0x017c: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 12  Cnt: 2  Name: GLIBC_2.29
  0x01bc: Parent 1: GLIBC_2.29
```

Once you have confirmed this, your problem should go away.

If it does not, you are *probably* running in a docker container with a *different version* of GLIBC installed.